# Creating A Counter In C# As A Repeatable Tool

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a very basic program that's essentially a few counters with buttons to increase/decrease the count that is pictured below.

[image]

The problem is I had to create each of the items somewhat independently so for every button there's a function rather than reusing them.

Is there anyway to essentially save the entire counter so that the label and buttons automatically go together and I don't have to recode the same thing multiple times?

Comment: You're looking for user controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `UserControl` called `Counter`, that provides whatever properties you need.  I would suggest you just need two properties: `Title` and `Count`.  You wire these up to the UI elements provided by your control.  If using WPF, this is pretty easy to do through XAML if you use Dependency Properties.

Comment: To expand upon this, you could also do a ScrollViewer with an ItemsControl. The ItemsSource for the ItemsControl could be a list of objects backing your counters. You could then modify that collection to let the user add/remove any number of counters as they save the app, and your collection could also be serializable.

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to find good tutorial to explain how to create and then implement a user control. Would you happen to have a link to one?

Comment: Are you using WPF or Forms?

Comment: Forms with VS2013 and Visual C#.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, but I know that you could make a class that groups all of your UI elements together:

"A class is a construct that enables you to create your own custom types by grouping together variables of other types, methods and events." From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/x9afc042.aspx).

So each counter could have the label, count, buttons and surrounding panel(s), and handle setting all of them up and adding them to the interface each time the class is initialized.